# jQuery slideToggle() particular object among many

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the jQuery `slideToggle()` method to try and display more information for a certain heading. I have created an example here:

http://ysk.co.za/slidetoggle/

My problem is when you click show more information for the one heading it shows more information for all the headings. How would I do this so that It only shows more information for that particular heading **without** having to `id` each button and `id` each paragraph and then make a new function for each in Javascript?

My HTML is:

```
        <div>
    <h2>The sun</h2>
    <button>Display more info</button>
    <p>The sun is shiny and is the symbol of daylight, it is a burning ball of gas</p>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
    <h2>The moon</h2>
    <button>Display more info</button>
    <p>The moon is a tiny planet and is the symbol night</p>
</div>
<hr>
```

My Javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").slideToggle("slow")
})
})
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find("p").slideToggle("slow")
    });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/H9QLH/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, works great! One seperate question: would you know how to make it change text depending on its toggle state, i.e if it is displayed the button says: "Hide" and if it is hidden the button says: "show"?

Comment: @YSK.CO welcome :) you want to change text of button?

Comment: Yes thats it, but based on if the information is showing the button must say hide and if the information is hidden the button should say show, as if: `toggleHtml()`

Answer (score 0):

The `p` element you want to target is the next sibling of the clicked button, so use [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $(this).next().stop(true, true).slideToggle("slow")
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eK5Yz/)